# ClassFormatError error while invoking method added using Java ASM

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am using Java ASM to add a method to compiled class. During run time I am getting
below error, when the newly added method is invoked.

```java
    ClassFormatError: Field "valueEquals" in class test/asm/Item has illegal signature "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z"
```

Below is the method which I expecting to add

```java
    public boolean valueEquals(Object obj){  
        return ItemHelper.valueEquals(obj);  
    }
```

Below is the asm code for this.

```java
    String methodName = "valueEquals";  
    MethodVisitor mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, methodName, "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z", null, null);  
    mv.visitCode();  
    mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 1);  
    mv.visitFieldInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "test/asm/ItemHelper", methodName, "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");  
    mv.visitInsn(IRETURN);  
    mv.visitMaxs(2, 1);  
    mv.visitEnd();
```

Please can some one help me in identifying what I am doing wrong here.
Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `visitMethodInsn` instead of `visitFieldInsn`, since you are calling a method, not accessing a field.